# How does Linux differentiate between opening a file in read mode and actually reading data from it?

Tags: files, python, timestamps

I created a simple text file and checked its timestamps using `stat` and here is the output:

> stat Output before any python script

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % stat prac09_timestamp.txt 
  File: prac09_timestamp.txt
  Size: 10          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2485542     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/papagolf)   Gid: ( 1001/papagolf)
Access: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
Modify: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
Change: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Then I ran a python script that simply opens the file in read mode. I was expecting the time "Access" stamp to change but it didn't.

> Python Script and output of stat after running it

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % cat python prac09_timestamp.py 
cat: python: No such file or directory
a = open("prac09_timestamp.txt", "r")
a.close()
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % python prac09_timestamp.py 
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % stat prac09_timestamp.txt 
  File: prac09_timestamp.txt
  Size: 10          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2485542     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/papagolf)   Gid: ( 1001/papagolf)
Access: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
Modify: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
Change: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
 Birth: -
```

But when I change the script to actually read the data, the time stamp changed. Can you explain it?

> New Python Script and output of stat after running it

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % cat prac09_timestamp.py 
a = open("prac09_timestamp.txt", "r")
a.readlines()
a.close()
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % python prac09_timestamp.py
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Python % stat prac09_timestamp.txt 
  File: prac09_timestamp.txt
  Size: 10          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 2485542     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/papagolf)   Gid: ( 1001/papagolf)
Access: 2017-09-10 11:13:12.699848321 +0530
Modify: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
Change: 2017-09-10 11:10:40.979845492 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Comment: I suppose the simple answer is that Python opening the file doesn't actually access the file. Which isn't really surprising. If you want to know what Python is doing when it opens the file, I guess you'd have to ask on a Python forum or look at the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a Python question at all. It's system level. And at that level opening a file is an entirely distinct operation from reading a file. I'm not an expert by any stretch of the imagination on Linux internals but here are some basic facts:

- A file is opened with the [`open()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) system call.
- A file is read with the [`read()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) system call
- There is a flag for `open()` that instructs the system to not update access time *when `read()` is called*. It's called `O_NOATIME`
- You can infer from this that `open()` itself doesn't update access time

If you think about what *access* means this makes sense. `open()` just returns a file descriptor that will allow you to do something (read and/or write) with the associated file later. To use a crude analogy, it's like having a ticket to a concert. Until you show up and start rocking out you haven't actually accessed anything. ;)